# Value of $\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{10000}}\right]$, where $[\cdot]$ is Box function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

How to find the value of this expression:
$$\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{10000}}\right]$$
where $[\cdot]$ is Box function (greatest integer less than or equal to).

The answer is 197. I solved numerically using Wolframalpha and the answer I'm getting is correct.

But there should must be another way of solving it, as this problem is from a 12th-grade competitive exam. I've tried to solve it using some law of surds but can't help it. Is there any analytical way of solving it?

Comment: Why not just carry this out numerically?

Comment: Compare it with the integral of $1/\sqrt{x}$

Comment: I've tried to solve it numerically but can't help it@Dr. MV

Comment: I've edited this question

Comment: What test is this, what grade are you in?

Comment: A competitive test, 12th

Comment: Include that the problem is from a 12th grade competitive exam and the question might be reopened and you might get some better answers.

Comment: I tweaked your answer just a wee bit, mainly to replace "ans" with "answer"...

Comment: See: <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945663/bounding-sum-of-reciprocals-of-the-square-roots-of-the-first-n-positive-integers>

Comment: This is a [similar post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168520/find-the-value-of-frac1-sqrt-2-frac1-sqrt-3-frac1-sqrt/2168984#2168984). Just change $1000 \mapsto 10000$. $\left\lfloor -1 + \,\sqrt{\, 10000\,}\,/\left(1/2\right) + \zeta\left(1/2\right)\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor 197.54\right\rfloor$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Answer Before I Noticed the Tags**

Comparing to integrals, we can use that
$$
\int_1^{10001}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}}\lt\sum_{k=1}^{10000}\frac1{\sqrt{k}}\lt1+\int_1^{10000}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}}
$$
The left side is $2\sqrt{10001}-2=198.00999975$ (using that $\sqrt{10000}=100$, we know that the sum is greater than $198$).

The right side is $1+2\sqrt{10000}-2=199$.

Therefore, just knowing that $\sqrt{10000}=100$, we can deduce that
$$
\left\lfloor\sum_{k=2}^{10000}\frac1{\sqrt{k}}\right\rfloor=198-1=197
$$

---

**Algebra-Precalculus Approach**

First, we have
$$
2\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right)=\frac2{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\lt\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\tag{1}
$$
Since $\sqrt{x}$ is concave, we have
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\lt\frac2{\sqrt{n+\frac12}+\sqrt{n-\frac12}}=2\left(\sqrt{n+\tfrac12}-\sqrt{n-\tfrac12}\right)\tag{2}
$$

Summing $(1)$:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^{10000}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}
&\gt2\sum_{n=2}^{10000}\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right)\\
&=2\sqrt{10001}-2\sqrt2\\
&=200.01-2.83\\
&=197.18
\end{align}
$$
Summing $(2)$:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^{10000}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}
&\lt2\sum_{n=2}^{10000}\left(\sqrt{n+\tfrac12}-\sqrt{n-\tfrac12}\right)\\
&=2\sqrt{10000.5}-2\sqrt{1.5}\\
&=200.005-2.449\\
&=197.556
\end{align}
$$